# Ошибка при перекодировке из 1251 в UTF8

Tags: python, python-3.x

мне нужно перекодировать файл из Windows-1251 в UTF-8, во время перекодировки получаю ошибку `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 0: invalid start byte` и в точности такую же ошибку получаю при при переводе строки в 1251 и обратно в UTF-8, как это можно исправить, почему не желает перекодировать

```
x='Байты'.encode('utf8')
print(x)
x='Байты'.encode('windows-1251')
print(x)
x=x.decode()
print(x)
```

вывод

```
b'\xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b'
b'\xc1\xe0\xe9\xf2\xfb
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: думаю потому что x.decode() по умолчанию декодирует из utf8, а у вас на тот момент x в windows-1251

Comment: И как перевести из  windows-1251 в UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

filename = 'in.txt'
tmpfilename = filename + '.new'

with open(filename, "r", encoding='windows-1251') as fin:
    txt = fin.read()

with open(tmpfilename, "w", encoding='utf8') as fout:
    fout.write(txt)

os.remove(filename)
os.rename(tmpfilename, filename)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, работает, очень много статей пересмотрел и не нашел, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

DrawnRaccoon вам правильно написал, что метод `decode` по умолчанию использует кодировку UTF-8, а в переменной `x` на момент вызова хранятся байты в кодировке cp1251. Это несоответствие фактической и ожидаемой кодировки и приводит к ошибке.

```
x = 'Байты'.encode('utf8')
print(x)  # В переменной x хранятся байты в кодировке utf-8

x = 'Байты'.encode('windows-1251')
print(x)  # В переменной x хранятся байты в кодировке сp1251

x = x.decode('windows-1251')
print(x)
```

Comment: Извините сделал аналогично с файлом text=text.decode('windows-1251') и open('file.txt','w').write(text) файл записался в кодировке windows-1251, а не в UTF-8

Comment: При открытии файла используется системная кодировка по умолчанию, если не указать параметр `encoding`.

Comment: Указываем кодировку при открытии  windows-1251 иначе мы не сможем его прочитать, далее  text=text.decode('windows-1251') и open('file.txt','w').write(text)  и файл записывается в windows-1251, а нужно в UTF-8

Comment: `open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: В этом вся проблема что encoding в utf-8 выдает ошибку где бы я не применял кодировку UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 10: invalid continuation byte для перекодировки файла